# How to convert edged image in OpenCV to svg file?

Tags: python, opencv, svg

I am using OpenCV canny edge detection module to find the contours of an image which gives me a B&W output image.

Here's the code for that:

```
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
  edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 180, 200)
```

Now I want to write this image to disk in SVG file format. How do I obtain the same from the cannied image?

Comment: Please be sure to post your complete code, and also the image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you want just the contours to be saved  as SVG image.

First, you need to compute the contours in your canny image using the findContorus function of [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html). Please be careful here, your contours MUST be well defined.

Second, having your contours just follow this question:

[Convert contour paths to svg paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108751/convert-contour-paths-to-svg-paths)

The SVG paths can be opened in any image processing software (e.g. Inkscape, Photoshop, etc)